# How to run a program on agent and capture the return code or string

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am setting up a simple pipeline in jenkins. At one stage I need to run a program that exists on the agent hard drive and capture the output. I have just a psudo code in mind, I have Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'MyAgent'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {                
                echo 'Hello World' + p_TargetDevice
             // Run a program on agent
             // var result = execute c:\test\program.exe 
             // if result = 0 then continue to next stage
             // else print/log the result and stop the pipeline

            }
        }
        
        stage('Bye') {
            steps {
                echo 'Goodbye World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows you can use `bat:` [Windows Batch Script Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) to execute your command and then use the option `returnStatus: true` to return the execution status. Check the following sample.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'MyAgent'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {                
             echo 'Hello World' + p_TargetDevice
          script {
                   command = 'execute c:\test\program.exe'
                   batExit = bat returnStatus: true,label: 'Test Code',
                         script: """
                              ${command}
                            """
                     echo "batExit = $batExit"
              }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Bye') {
            steps {
                echo 'Goodbye World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get an error like this `WorkflowScript: : Expected a step `

Comment: Try wrapping commands in a script block. Check the updated Ppeline.